# Join tables based on ID

Tags: arcpy, python, update

I have 2 tables. Each table has an ID and i need to insert only one attribute from first table to a specific field in the second table using python script. This should be done using UpdateCursor, but i can't figure out how, Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

Many options.

First, you can use [Join Field from Data Management](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/join-field.htm)

Second, you can create a new field, join the second table with [Add Join from Data Management](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-join.htm) and then calculate your newly created field with simple excpression [table1.TARGETFIELD] = [table2.JOINEDFIELD]

Third, you can read everything to python dicitionary {id: value} with SearchCursor:

```
joined_data = {row[0]: row[1] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table2, ['ID', 'JOINEDFIELD']}
```

and than update your first table with UpdateCursor:

```
default_value = _write_your_default_value_here_
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table1, ['ID', 'TARGETFIELD']) as uc:
    for row in uc:
        row[1] = joined_data.get(row[0], default_value)
        uc.updateRow(row)
```

Don't forget to build attribute indexes if you'd use first two options.

Actually, it's almost the same situation as described [in this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/237293/80678)